# Etymology of the word 'roach' to mean the end of a marijuana cigarette?

Tags: etymology, slang

I was contemplating the German word "Rauch" (smoke or fumes) and the closely related "rauchte" (smoked) and "Rauchen" (smoking). These are related to the English word 'reek', and I wonder if they might also be related to the use of the word "roach" to refer to the butt of a marijuana cigarette.

Any insights?

Comment: No. The term _roach_ comes from the cockroach metaphor in the Mexican revolutionary folksong [_La Cucaracha_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Cucaracha#Revolutionary_lyrics): _La cucaracha, la cucaracha, ya no puede caminar; porque no tiene, porque le falta, marihuana que fumar'._

Comment: I think any answer should focus on the im-/possibility of roach being a regular by-form of reak. I can't tell from the top of my hat, and it might be totally misguided to require a millenia old heritage for a slang word about a cultural practice which was as far as I know not that old at all. Ido like to compare *Rauch* with *Rohr*, by the way, for the latter has no certain etymology and means literally "duct, pipe; reed" (a denominal \*rohren would be practicly homophone with v. *rauchen* in my parts). No word for *roach* lies nearer than *cockroach* anyhow...

Comment: and the supposed derivatiin of *cigar* from *cigarro* "male cicada", though uncertain, as well as the Spanish avenue for Tobacco into europe in general make it very likely. Very unlikely in contrast is that *cock-* should have anything to do with *tap water plumbing* (see *cock* ~ Ger. *Hahn* "faucette"), nor with the rooster (as a size category, I say), though I see no etymology for the *-racha* in *cucaracha*. German translates *Küchen-* "kitchen", akin to *cook*, that would count as folk etymology...

Comment: *cigarro* could itself be a folk etymology. Likewise, wiktionary notes that the *roach* in *cockroach* came under folketymology influence from *roach*, but they list two or three different entries. Regardless of cucaracha, I figure that for the filter tip end of a roled cigarette, ety 3 of "roach" comes close: "(nautical) An extra curve of material added to the... " ([wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/roach)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The origin of roach in the marijuana sense is not clear, but among the different assumptions there is no reference to German words:

Roach is the short for cockroach on the wrong notion that it was a compond:

***[Roach](https://www.etymonline.com/word/roach):***

> - Meaning "butt of a marijuana cigarette" is first recorded 1938, perhaps from resemblance to the insect, but perhaps a different word entirely.

(Etymonline)

***[Roach:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/roach)***

> - narcotics sense perhaps from earlier roach mane, a horse's mane clipped very short and tied; perhaps from the insect.

(The Dictionary of American Slang)

another possible origin is from Spanish *[tobacco de cucaracha](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roach_(smoking))*:

> - In Spanish, tabaco de cucaracha ("roach tobacco") refers to powdery, low-quality tobacco.

(Wikipedia)